# Merging two nested JSON arrays

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm working with a form built dynamically in JavaScript from a JSON schema that looks like this:

```
{
  "questionSets": [
    {
      "questionSetId": "example-fields",
      "questions": [
        {
          "questionId": "text",
          "question": "Text Field",
          "input": {
            "type": "textInput",
            "default": ""
          },
        },
        {
          "questionId": "textarea",
          "question": "Text Area",
          "input": {
            "type": "textareaInput",
            "default": ""
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When the form is submitted it just returns the updated values that look like this:

```
{
  text: "some entered text", 
  textarea: "some more entered text"
}
```

The keys of this resulting JSON array correspond with the **questionId** and the value with the **default** key in the first array.

What's the best way to go about merging these 2 arrays so the result is:

```
{
  "questionSets": [
    {
      "questionSetId": "example-fields",
      "questions": [
        {
          "questionId": "text",
          "question": "Text Field",
          "input": {
            "type": "textInput",
            "default": "some entered text"
          },
        },
        {
          "questionId": "textarea",
          "question": "Text Area",
          "input": {
            "type": "textareaInput",
            "default": "some more entered text"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe make a function that creates an empty array, and iterate through the results and append to the empty array accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a tricky one. The simplest way is using [`underscore`](http://underscorejs.org). Let `reply` be your input object, and `defaultInputs` the object with the default inputs to be filled out in the JSON.

```
'use strict';

let _ = require('underscore');

module.exports = function (defaultInputs, reply) {

    reply.questionSets = _.map(reply.questionSets, questionSet => {
        questionSet.questions = _.map(questionSet.questions, question => {
            question.input.default = _.find(defaultInputs,(item, key) => (
                new RegExp(`${key}Input`).test(question.input.type) && item
            ) || false) || '';

            return question;
        });
        return questionSet;
    });

    return reply;
};
```

A proper code solution (including the test) can be found [here](https://github.com/pandres95/stackoverflow-36562030).

---

**UPDATE (07/01/2018)**

Now it's possible to achieve the same via the new Array prototype functions like [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (defaultInputs, reply) {

    reply.questionSets = reply.questionSets.map(questionSet => {
        questionSet.questions = questionSet.questions.map(question => {
            question.input.default = defaultInputs.filter((item, key) => (
                new RegExp(`${key}Input`).test(question.input.type) && item
            ) || false) || '';

            return question;
        });
        return questionSet;
    });

    return reply;
};
```